# How to pass time limit to dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I was trying this problem as follows:
A number is said to be a 369 number if:

- The count of 3s is equal to count of 6s and the count of 6s is equal to count of 9s.
- The count of 3s is at least 1.

For Example 12369, 383676989, 396 all are 369 numbers whereas 213, 342143, 111 are not.

Given A and B find how many 369 numbers are there in the interval [A, B]. Print the answer modulo 10^9+7

I approached to the problem making dp sol as follow but getting time limit exceeded

```
long long  rec(vector<int>&v,int index,bool status,int cnt3,int cnt6,int cnt9)
{  
    sz=v.size()/3;
    if(cnt3>sz || cnt6>sz || cnt9>sz)
        return 0;
    if(index==v.size() && cnt3 && cnt3==cnt6 && cnt6==cnt9)
        return 1;
    else if(index==v.size())
        return 0;
    ll &ret=dp[index][status][cnt3][cnt6][cnt9];
    if(ret==-1)
    {
        ret=0;
        bool newstatus;
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
        {
            if(status && i>v[index] )
                break;
            newstatus=status && (i==v[index]);
            if(i==3)
                ret+=rec(v,index+1,newstatus,cnt3+1,cnt6,cnt9);
            else if(i==6)
                ret+=rec(v,index+1,newstatus,cnt3,cnt6+1,cnt9);
            else if(i==9)
                ret+=rec(v,index+1,newstatus,cnt3,cnt6,cnt9+1);
            else
                ret+=rec(v,index+1,newstatus,cnt3,cnt6,cnt9);
            ret%=mod;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Can anyone help me to optimize this?

Comment: Is this in C? (Should it be tagged as such?) Are you necessarily constrained to using that for your answer?

Comment: How large can A and B be?

Comment: I know that the problem (as stated) is that you have to achieve this within a given time limit, but is that actually an appropriate title for the question?

Comment: There are also analytical, mathematical approaches to the problem, which are almost certain to perform better than a brute force search.

Answer (score 2):

### Early termination

One simple change that might stop a lot of states from needing to be explored is to compute m=max(cnt3,cnt6,cnt9).

In order to have matching counts, you must increase cnt3 by m-cnt3, cnt6 by m-cnt6, cnt9 by m-cnt9.

You have v.size()-index digits still to assign, so you can add the following extra test at the start of your function

```
if (v.size()-index < m*3-cnt3-cnt6-cnt9)
  return 0;
```

### Compress state space 1

In addition, if I understand the logic correctly, once status becomes false you are allowed any choice of digit.  From this point on the results will be the same for any permutation of cnt3,cnt6,cnt9 so you could sort these 3 numbers in order to cut down state space even more.

### Compress state space 2

Similarly, once all the counts are above 1, you don't care by how much so you can change numbers such as:

```
cnt3=3,cnt6=7,cnt9=8
```

to

```
cnt3=1,cnt6=5,cnt9=6
```

and this should result in you needing to search less space.

Comment: "Compress state space 1" is the key here which allows for a linear time solution.